# What is the name of this red creature card

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In Magic the Gathering I played a guy that was using a mono - red goblin deck which exploited [Impact Tremors](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394600) ability with a certain creature that "blinks" out of the game when another spell is cast now I cant for the life of me remember the name of the card.

I tried the card database on Magic wizards and got no luck. All that I can remember was that it was mono - red goblin creature of some sort. that had something a long the lines of this in its effect text:
"Whenever a spell is cast remove (said creature) from the game until end of turn then return it to the battlefield".

Can anyone help me out? I really want to obtain this card...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The card you are looking for is [Norin the Wary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=norin%20the%20wary). I found this by searching on magiccards.info for

> c!r t:creature o:"Exile ~" o:return

This searches for a mono-red (c!r) creature (t:creature) that has in its text "Exile [this creature]" and "return [to the battlefield]". That resulted in only two cards, and only one triggered on casting a spell.

Comment: A similar query in Gatherer returns 18 possible cards.  One of which is Norin the Wary.  http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=+[R]&type=+[%22Creature%22]&text=+[exile]+[end]+[of]+[turn]+[battlefield]+[return]

Comment: It seems like that search found more cards because it's less restrictive regarding color and card text. And Norin the Wary is the only one in that list that does what the question described.

Comment: I said it was a goblin creature not a human but that card has a similar affect only it didn't activate on attacking with a creature.

Comment: Maybe it is something like http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391874 , or something else with a dash ability?

Comment: @NathanTaylor, I think it's pretty certain that this is your intended card even though it isn't a goblin. Because firstly, this is a very popular card that abuses enter the battlefield abilities, and secondly, The only red goblin that even uses the word "exile" is Lightning Crafter, something totally different. Note that "remove from the game" as you stated in your question does not exist anymore, it is renamed to "exile", so when you do a card search you should use exile

Comment: @IvoBeckers it may be an old card then but it was definitely a goblin as it had a goblin as the picture and it was a constant effect not a dash ability i'm not sure where it was from...

Comment: @NathanTaylor even very old cards that do have old wording printed on it will have updated Oracle Text. This is the leading rule of the card and it is this text that is searched for when using card search engines. There simply is no red Goblin card in existence that has "exile" (or removed from the game) other than Lightning Crafter

Comment: @NathanTaylor How sure are you, really, that the actual card type was Goblin? When I first saw Norin the Wary, I thought it *was* a goblin because of the picture.

Comment: @murgatroid99 He was using other cards that had affects for goblin creatures on the field the guy goes to my Friday night magic i'll ask him cus its killing me haha

Comment: That would help. But you should know that Norin the Wary is the only red creature ever printed that has an effect that's even remotely similar to the one you described.

Comment: @NathanTaylor This is your card. Period.

Comment: I may have gotten some of the description wrong im not sure I working from very little recollection I just know that it kicked my ass and I want it :P

Comment: @NathanTaylor Then perhaps buy it, and select this as the answer?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding guys this was my card :)